# Update profile pic using PaperClip (Rails 4)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, paperclip

I have some problems on for example, updating a profile picture for the current user logged in.

```
#form for the picture
    <%= form_tag '/update_profile_pic/'+user.id.to_s, method: :put, html: { multipart: true } do %>
        <%= label_tag :avatar %>
        <%= file_field_tag :avatar %>
        <%= submit_tag("Update", class: "btn btn-primary") %>
    <% end %>

#users_controller.rb
class UsersController < ApplicationController
    def update_profile_pic
        @user = User.find(params[:id])
        @user.avatar = params[:avatar]
        if @user.save
            flash[:success] = "Profile picture updated."
        else
            flash[:danger] = "Failed to update profile picture."
        end
    end
end

#user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessbile :avatar

    has_attached_file :avatar, styles: { tiny: "30x30>", thumb: "50x50>", profile: "100x100>" }, 
    default_url: "/assets/images/users/:style/default.png",
    url: "/assets/images/users/:id/:style/:basename.:extension",
    path: ":rails_root/public/assets/images/users/:id/:style/:basename.:extension"

    validates_attachment_size :avatar, less_than: 5.megabytes
    validates_attachment_content_type :avatar, content_type: ["image/jpeg", "image/png"]
end
```

After submitting the form together with the selected picture, I got this exception: `Paperclip::AdapterRegistry::NoHandlerError - No handler found for "me.jpg"`. Adding a profile pic upon signing up (which is create users) works but changing the picture as a signed in user does not work. It seems that `@user.avatar = params[:avatar]` seems a bit stupid thing to do.

Answer (score 0):

Try with :

@user.update_attributes(params)

Comment: it's working now, but not dependent on the problem with the params. i'll put it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I just noticed two things:

1. The rendered form's header from the signup and update avatar are different in terms of its multipart parameter. From the signup, it was `enctype=multipart/form-date`, while the other was only, `html: { multipart: true }`.
2. Because of item #1, I noticed that that the parameters for making the form as a multipart is different for `form_for` and `form_tag` respectively.

So I changed `html: { multipart: true }` to `multipart: true` instead.

```
#form for the picture
<%= form_tag '/update_profile_pic/'+user.id.to_s, method: :put, multipart: true do %>
    <%= label_tag :avatar %>
    <%= file_field_tag :avatar %>
    <%= submit_tag("Update", class: "btn btn-primary") %>
<% end %>
```

Irregardless of the params for updating the avatar from what I gave and from the person who answered my question, they both worked.